# How to conditionally unset header in .htaccess file?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to conditionally unset `X-Frame-Options` in an `.htaccess` file if the request URL begins with `/store`. This is the code I am working with in `.htaccess`:

```
# Allow store iframe to be loaded from all locations
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/store" iframe
Header always unset X-Frame-Options env=iframe
```

But this isn't working and the `X-Frame-Options` header continues to be sent.

The web server is running Apache 2.2.

If I remove the `SetEnvIf` line and the `env=iframe` part of the third line the `X-Frame-Options` header is removed. What is wrong with my `SetEnvIf` condition?

Comment: Your `SetEnvIf` directive looks OK. (I would be surprised if mod_setenvif was not enabled, since it is one of the standard Apache modules - but wouldn't you get a 500 error if it wasn't available?) Are you performing any URL rewrites? Try removing the `always` keyword - although that probably is not the problem given your last paragraph.

Comment: Just checked via apachectl and mod_setenvif is loaded. No 500 errors are occurring so that would also suggest mod_setenvif is working ok, as @MrWhite said. We do have some rewrites in .htaccess to route requests to index.php, but presumably Request_URI would still remain constant. Is it possible to return Request_URI in a custom header to identify what value Request_URI actually has? That might help with debugging.

Comment: As you suggest, try assigning it to another environment variable to check... `SetEnvIf Request_URI "(.*)" MYURI=$1`. And read `MYURI` in your application.

Comment: ...and to assign it to a custom header: `Header set X-Test %{MYURI}e`

Comment: I did the test header and it turns out the Request_URI is /index.php: `X-Test => /index.php` so it does seem our rewrite rules are the cause of this.

Comment: can't you do this "without .htaccess"? As in, aren't you the admin of the site?

Comment: Yes, that's possible - i've done it through PHP for the time being but wanted to know if it could be done through .htaccess with a conditional rule.